# REGEX Capturing differing sets of repeating groups

Tags: regex, pcre, repeat

this is a two-part question, but I feel the answers will be related.

I have this regex pattern:
`(\d+)(aa|bb)` which I use to capture this string: `1bb2aa3aa4bb5bb6aa7bb8cc9cc`

See demo: [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/FC9gKz/4)

The way it captures the random series of aa and bb (both preceded by a digit) is exactly what I want, and is good as far as it goes.

So we get this match on regex101:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-3 `1bb`
Group 1.    0-1 `1`
Group 2.    1-3 `bb`
Match 2
Full match  3-6 `2aa`
Group 1.    3-4 `2`
Group 2.    4-6 `aa`
Match 3
Full match  6-9 `3aa`
Group 1.    6-7 `3`
Group 2.    7-9 `aa`
Match 4
Full match  9-12    `4bb`
Group 1.    9-10    `4`
Group 2.    10-12   `bb`
Match 5
Full match  12-15   `5bb`
Group 1.    12-13   `5`
Group 2.    13-15   `bb`
Match 6
Full match  15-18   `6aa`
Group 1.    15-16   `6`
Group 2.    16-18   `aa`
Match 7
Full match  18-21   `7bb`
Group 1.    18-19   `7`
Group 2.    19-21   `bb`
```

As expected, the `8cc9cc`bit at the end is ignored. I would like capture this as well, in the same way I have captured the first repeating groups, in the same expression. So in the final output, I'd get something like this added to the end of the output. This should work for any amounts of matches on either side. This text is just one example.

```
Full match  21-24   `8cc`
Group 1.    21-22   `8`
Group 2.    22-24   `cc`
Match 7
Full match  24-27   `9cc`
Group 1.    24-25   `9`
Group 2.    25-27   `cc`
```

Also, I'd like to do similar but flipping the 'or' group to the end i.e. this:

```
1cc2cc3cc4cc5cc6cc7ccb8aa9bb
```

My current regex pattern `(\\d+)(cc)` only matches the repeating 'cc' groups.
See demo: [example 2](https://regex101.com/r/FC9gKz/6)

I would like a similar full capture, with any amount of permissible entries of each group.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So, tried [`(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)`](https://regex101.com/r/oXW2sK/1)?

Comment: Yes, that technically does capture it, but I don't want random 'or's of all three strings. I want a series of aa  bb combos THEN a cc group (or just one cc). And also, presumably using a different regex pattern, a series of cc, THEN some aa bb combos. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Also, please add the regex falvor tag to the question.

Comment: Just don't say "I need to make it work at regex101.com and later I will use it in a C# app". Some people write PCRE and then try to use the regex in Python `re`. Really, that is sad.

Comment: You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/FC9gKz/11) to find any number of xaa or xbb matches followed by any number of xcc matches. As you can see it doesn't match if this pattern isn't met. Then you can use Wiktor's pattern to break it up into capture groups.

Comment: It is pcre. I have updated the tags.

Comment: What about 8aa9bb0bb3cc2bb? Is that valid or should every piece end with "cc" once a "cc" match is made?

Comment: Ok, it is PCRE, but do you want to get something like [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%28aa%7cbb%29%29%2b%28%3f%3a%28%5cd%2b%29%28cc%29%29*&i=1bb2aa3aa4bb5bb6aa7bb8cc9cc) (go to `Table` tab at the bottom and expand *`Captures`*)?

Comment: Hi @emsimpson92, no that's not valid. it is any combination of aa and bb THEN any number of cc groups.

Comment: OP I updated the pattern in my comment

Comment: So @emsimpson92 that would capture 8aa9bb0bb3cc. This would be fine. Another point is that I need to capture all the groups i.e. the number values and strings as output in my original question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry if I was not clear. we can have: 1aa2aa3bb THEN 1cc2cc3cc4cc etc. any combo aa and bb always in the left of the string. On the right side of string, any amount of cc. Not mixed up. And I need to capture the repeating groups (as in regex101).

Comment: After reading all your comments, I assume you just have a typo in `1cc2cc3cc4cc5cc6cc7ccb8aa9bb` - there should be no `b` before `8`, right?

Comment: It's not clear. After reading comments, you want to match the first sequence of the pattern in order with any characters before and after the sequence. [See php demo (click *run code*)](https://www.phprun.org/cDkPdD).

Comment: Yes there is a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\dcc))|(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/17)

The regex will only match the string that meets the pattern in the `(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+)` lookahead, and then will consecutively match and capture digits and `aa`, `bb` or `cc`, but digits + `aa` or `bb` will be matched unless digits + `cc` is not in front.

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\dcc))|(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+))` - either of the two alternatives:

  - `\G(?!^)` - end of the previous successful match
  - `(?(?=\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\dcc))` - if-then-else construct: if there is 1+ digits and `aa` or `bb` immediately to the right of the current location (`(?=\d+(?:aa|bb)`), then only continue matching if there is no digit followed with `cc` immediately to the left of the current location (`(?<!\dcc)`)
  - `|` - or
  - `^` - start of string
  - `(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+)`  - a positive lookahead that, immediately to the right of the current location, searches for the following (and returns true if it finds the patterns, or false if it does not):

    - `(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+` - one or more occurrences of 1+ digits followed with `aa` or `bb`
    - `(?:\d+cc)+` - one or more occurrences of 1+ digits followed with `cc`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(aa|bb|cc)` - `aa`, `bb` or `cc`.

For the second pattern, [replace `cc` with `(?:aa|bb)`](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/18):

```
(?:\G(?!^)(?(?=\d+cc)(?<!\d(?:aa|bb)))|(?=(?:\d+cc)+(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)
```

Comment: When skynet takes over, my money is on Wiktor saving the human race by creating a malicious regex pattern that causes their CPU to overheat. I learn something new from you every day.

Comment: @emsimpson92 I doubt a regex will be able to do that since it only operates on *text* data, but to cause catastrophic backtracking, one does not really have to know regex well. I guess vice versa :) I fixed my description of the lookahead.

Comment: Thanks for your work on this. You have nearly cracked it. However, the string will be part of a bigger string. In your solution, if we add anything on the end, it will not match e.g. [link](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/3) Here I have added an X. Sorry if I did not specify that.

Comment: @Funtboy That is not a problem, [remove `$` in the lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/4). `$` requires end of string.

Comment: This would be the full solution if you want to allow for text before the series as well: [`(?:\G(?!^)|(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)`](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/7)

Comment: @emsimpson92 [`(?:\G(?!^)|^.*?(?=(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\d+cc)+))(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)`](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/8)? Well, this can be enhanced to any extent needed.

Comment: That's what I used originally, but then you have problems if their input is split. i.e. `hr1bb2aa3afgd4bb5bb6aa7bb8cc9ccXdf`. Not sure if that is a problem for OP. I guess either way it's a problem.

Comment: This is great work from both of you . You have answered my question as stated . I now realise that my requirements are more demanding. I could ask another question if you want me to. The problem is that I would need to allow for  two or more instances of this capture.  In the way this regex captures two simple groups of cc [link](https://regex101.com/r/12mbSn/1).

Comment: It is the same question, do not ask a dupe.

Comment: Fair point @WiktorStribiżew. Consider this solution [link](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/15) It is nearly there, but notice that it has captured the rogue '10bb' at the end of the first string and '10aa' at the end of the second. '10bb11cc' would be okay here but not just 10bb.

Comment: @Funtboy I understand it that you want to stop matching `\d+` if the `\d+cc` has been just matched. Try https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/17, the `(?(?=\d+(?:aa|bb))(?<!\dcc))` part will make sure that, if the next substring matches `\d+aa` or `\d+bb`, the preceding chars cannot be `\dcc`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works beautifully. Thanks very much. I will attempt to make it work for the the second example, but may poke you if I struggle.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, I can't see the update but I see you placed the second parse in [https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/18](https://regex101.com/r/m4UD0j/18). And it also works perfectly! Great stuff.

Comment: I don't want to edit your answer bit those regex links ending in 17 and 18 are the answers. Cheers again.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert with perl, so I'll give a bit of pseudo code here. Feel free to suggest an edit.

You can start by matching any number of xaa or xbb combos, followed by one or more xcc combos using this pattern: `^(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\dcc)+$`

Once you have that you can use this pattern to capture the appropriate groups: `(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)`

[Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/FC9gKz/11)

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/FC9gKz/12)

Something like:

```
if(ismatch("^(?:\d+(?:aa|bb))+(?:\dcc)+$", inputString))
{
  match = match("(\d+)(aa|bb|cc)", inputString);
}
```

from here you can extract the information using the groups.

Comment: Yes hello, as above, I do not want to mix cc and aa bb combos. One series must follow the other. I realise I am looking for two different regex patterns.